# How can I set up a minimal c++ makefile and project structure in windows, to be run via command line?

Tags: c++, windows, makefile

**Analogous setup on *nix:**

There is a single project folder with a makefile, and directories for src, build, and target.
In the src directory, I put main.cpp, and other source files (file_0.cpp, file_0.h, file_1.cpp, file_1.h, etc...).

Invoking the makefile (via `make`, or similar one-line [preferably one-word] script) does nothing fancier than check the src folder if *anything* is newer than the target, and if so, rebuilds the whole project. (Alternatively, a batch file that just does the compilation regardless of filesystem state would also be "fine"- though I'd prefer a makefile as I could iteratively grow that in complexity as necessary.)

The "build" folder could be used for intermediate build files.

**Questions:**

What do I need to install? How must I set up my environment? What compilers/tools should I lean into so I'm not fighting the OS? Etc...

My needs for these projects are minimal. The point here is I DON'T want to have to rely on booting up a heavy IDE or similar to putz around with simple C++ projects. Is this achievable in Windows 10?

**Problems:**

I've tried installing mingw, with msys, and can get `cl` to produce a `.exe`, but when I invoke it via a `makefile`, I get `LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'LIBCMT.lib'`. I've been struggling to find "makefile" resources for windows, as many appear to be straddling different tech stacks (`cl` vs `g++`, `make` vs `nmake`, etc...)

Comment: Perhaps this could help: [Makefiles and Visual Studio](https://cognitivewaves.wordpress.com/makefiles/)

Comment: Had some success with cmake and cl in the past. You may need to configure a libpath to get round you linker error there, but cmake seemed to do a pretty good job out of the box iirc.

Comment: I've found the simplest setup is to install the VS build tools + optionally VS code. Launch code through the build tools command prompt will ensure the environment is configured correctly, you can then adapt your current Makefile to make it work with MS's nmake.